# Trigger to update boolean not working when similar trigger to update integer is working fine?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers, boolean

I've got 2 tables, lowlevel_table and toplevel_table. Basically the lowlevel rows are contained in the toplevel one

lowlevel_table

```
id integer 
status integer
flag boolean 
geom geometry point
```

toplevel_table

```
id integer 
status integer
flag boolean 
geom geometry polygon
```

When a user updates status value on a row on the toplevel table or the flag to false, the value needs to be passed to all the lowlevel_table rows that are contained inside. Currently the status one works fine but even though the flag one is coded very similar, it is not working

Working status trigger and function

```
create trigger status_update before
update of status on
toplevel_table for each row
when  (new.status > old.status) execute function status_update()

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION status_update()
RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

 BEGIN  
 if new.status > old.status then 
 update lowlevel_table a set status = new.status where a.status < new.status  
 and st_contains(a.geom, st_centroid(new.geom) );
 end if;
 RETURN NEW;                                                                    
 END;
    
 $function$
 ;
```

NOT working trigger and function

```
create trigger flag_update before
update of flag on
toplevel_table for each row
when  (new.flag is false) execute function flag_update()

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION flag_update()
RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

 BEGIN  
 if new.flag is false then 
 update lowlevel_table a set flag = new.flag where a.flag is true 
 and st_contains(a.geom, st_centroid(new.geom) );
 end if;
 RETURN NEW;                                                                    
 END;
    
 $function$
 ;
```

Update query

```
 update toplevel_table set status = 5 where id = myid
 update toplevel_table set flag = false where id = myid
```

I really can't understand why my boolean trigger does not work when it's written the exact way. How to make it work?

Comment: What is the error you get? And why don't you do that in a single trigger and a single update statement? That would be much more efficient

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't get any errors, it's just that the lowlevel table doesnt get updated in the flag one.

I thought about it but the trigger statements are different, users usually change statuses a lot but rarely use the flag. Users also change other columns that dont impact the lowlevel table. This is how I can only trigger when updating these two columns, I wasn't successful in using "OR" in the trigger statement

Comment: This is a poor design. Both `status` and `flag` each qualify as *one data point* and represent the same in both tables. But that means you are storing single data points in multiple places. Then running up against the truism *if you store one piece of data in two places then one of them is wrong*.  You should drop both from `lowlevel` table. When needed just get the value from the parent table, after-all you already have the relationship (FK?).  As an extra benefit it entirely removes the triggers from the picture.

Comment: @Belayer this has nothing to do with the question itself but if you must know, there are a dozen "lowlevel tables" and at certain stages they can have a higher status than the top level table, especially flags will mean different things and mobilize different teams into action